# Secure WebSocket with Spring Security OAuth 2.0, AngularJS and SockJs

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm trying to implement WebSocket support with Angular+SockJs on front-end, and Spring on backend. We are using Spring Security with OAuth 2.0 token based authorization.
Spec [tell us](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/src/asciidoc/web-websocket.adoc#token-based-authentication) that i should pass token via STOMP client at connect time and use Interceptor on backend to provide Principal. But i don't like this approach because i need to copy logic from Security configuration to get Principal from Token.
Is it possible to catch SockJs request in Angular Interceptor and add Authentication header?